# Disable Weld-SE startup debug logging level when running unit tests

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, weld-se

I have some tests in my project and when I run them through IntelliJ, I get many lines of logging statements from WELD. I can't figure out how to disable them or set them at WARNING or higher level.

This is the current output every time I run a Test class in intelliJ (attached photo):

```
18:25:31.951 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
18:25:31.980 [main] INFO org.jboss.weld.Version - WELD-000900: 2.4.7 (Final)
18:25:32.053 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap - WELD-ENV-000030: Cannot load class using the ResourceLoader: org.jboss.jandex.Index
18:25:32.242 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.266 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.293 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.313 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.329 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.341 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.375 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.390 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.402 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.414 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.425 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.438 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.449 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.460 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.470 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.489 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.501 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.512 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.522 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
18:25:32.532 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: ...
```

[IntelliJ Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOu34.png)

Expected outcome:

Show only WARN or ERROR or higher level messages or completely disable the logging statements of Weld Container and Context instantiation.

Is there a way to configure weld-se logging to be disabled or show only warn or error log statements?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include details on what exactly your problem is -- what is the expected behaviour of these tests and why are these Debug messages a problem? Thanks!